# How To Set Height of Child Div According To Parent Div

Tags: html, css, xhtml, height

I have a html like this:

```
<div id="container">    
    <div id="c1">       
    </div>
    <div id="c2">       
    </div>
</div>
```

And I have this css codes:

```
    <style type="text/css">
html, body {
    height: 100%;
    }
body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0; 
    }
#container {
    height: 100%;
    background: #CCFFCC;
    }
#c2{
    background: #CC11CC;
    min-height: 100%;   
}
#c1{
    background: #CC44AA;
    height: 50px;
}
</style>
```

I want c2 div's height to expand as %100 of parent div minus c1's height. Because I don't want scroll to be shown in my page. How can i do it?

How can i do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a soliton like that, and it works:

http://jsfiddle.net/Us5Cn/

Answer (score 1):

You have to add the space of the topmost element as a margin to your c2 div and tell the browser to calculate the rest of the height with `width: autoM`:

```
#c2{
    background: #CC11CC;
    height: auto;   
    margin-top: 50px; /*equal to height of #c1*/
}
#c1{
    background: #CC44AA;
    height: 50px;
}
```

[Here's an example](http://jsfiddle.net/Kyle_Sevenoaks/cNEgm/).

This should make it display as you expect. :)

---

[**Updated** example](http://jsfiddle.net/Kyle_Sevenoaks/cNEgm/2/):

```
#c1{
    background: #blue;
    height: 50px;
}

#c2{
    background: #orange;
    height: 100%;   
}
```

Comment: Thanks for reply. In your example c2'is expanding according to their content. But I want it to has a height 100% of window minus c1's height, even it's empty.

Comment: Unfortunately, this doesn't appear to work in Chrome. The only way I've found to do cross-browser dynamic height is jQuery.

Comment: I think I will do it with jquery. Thanks for advises.